# curl: (6) Could not resolve host: application

Tags: curl

Getting **url: (6) Could not resolve host: application** error after this command :

```
curl -i -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"Code":"FR","Name":"France"}' http://127.0.0.1:8080/countries
```

**Full error log:**

```
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: application
HTTP/1.1 415 Unsupported Media Type
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
X-Powered-By: go-json-rest
Date: Sat, 02 Apr 2016 05:31:20 GMT
Content-Length: 73

{
"Error": "Bad Content-Type or charset, expected 'application/json'"
}
```

What's wrong with this command?

**Edit:**

I solved my problem editing like this in windows : `"{/"Code/":/"FR/"}"`

Answer (score 228, accepted):

In my case, putting space after colon was wrong.

```
# Not work
curl -H Content-Type: application/json ~
# OK
curl -H Content-Type:application/json ~
```

Comment: This explains why none of my Surveymonkey API requests with json data were working.  Thank you!

Comment: On Windows I was also able to fix it by using `"` instead of `'`. Not work: `curl -H 'Accept: application/json'`. Work: `curl -H "Accept: application/json"`.

Comment: It seems like using `'`single quotes`'` on Windows just causes all kinds of problems which are difficult to diagnose because the errors often make no sense. Using `-v` should clear things up.

Answer (score 22):

I replaced all the single quotes ['] to double quotes ["] and then it worked perfectly. Thanks for the input by @LogicalKip.

Comment: I had a space after my colon and also I didn't use double quotes

Answer (score 20):

It's treating the string `application` as your URL. 
This means your shell isn't parsing the command correctly. 
 My guess is that you copied the string from somewhere, and that when you pasted it, you got some characters that looked like regular quotes, but weren't.
Try retyping the command; you'll only get valid characters from your keyboard. I bet you'll get a much different result from what looks like the same query.
As this is probably a shell problem and not a 'curl' problem (you didn't build cURL yourself from source, did you?), it might be good to mention whether you're on Linux/Windows/etc.

Comment: Did you try retyping it yet?

Comment: I solved my problem. In windows I have to type like this : "{/"Code/":/"FR/"}"

Comment: I had a similar problem. My command contained no double quotes, the argument was between single quotes. I replaced them with double quotes, it worked. On Windows as well.

Answer (score 16):

Example for Slack.... (use your own web address you generate there)...

`curl -X POST -H "Content-type:application/json" --data "{\"text\":\"A New Program Has Just Been Posted!!!\"}" https://hooks.slack.com/services/T7M0PFD42/BAA6NK48Y/123123123123123`

Comment: @pomply Could you please elaborate a bit more? Did you literally try the example above? What error message did you get?

Answer (score 9):

I was getting this error too. I resolved it by installing:
 https://git-scm.com/

and running the command from the Git Bash window.

Answer (score 6):

For my issue using curl on Windows 10 with the environment variable already setup,

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" --data "{\"jsonrpc\":\"2.0\",\"method\":\"eth_blockNumber\",\"params\":[],\"id\":83}" https://some-node-url.com
```

I needed to replace all single quotes `'` with double quotes `"`

even though the example for the blockchain I was trying to curl to had a single quote.

And also add `\` in front of all the double quotes inside the param brackets `{}`

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I copied the curl command from Confluence to TextEdit. After spending almost an hour, and trying to paste the command in different text editors in order to sanitize, finally, PyCharm helped me (IntelliJ should help too)

After pasting it in PyCharm I got to see the error

[image: Non-breaking spaces]

After removing these "NBSP" (non-breaking spaces), the command started running fine.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was a missing line break that added unneeded parameters due to a bad copy and paste.

I followed a guide at https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/windows.html#include-optional-components which looks like this when you copy it right here without any editing:

> REM Make sure you have 7z and curl installed.
>
> REM Download MKL files

```
curl https://s3.amazonaws.com/ossci-windows/mkl_2020.0.166.7z -k -O 7z x -aoa mkl_2020.0.166.7z -omkl
```

Output:

```
C:\Users\Admin>curl "https://s3.amazonaws.com/ossci-windows/mkl_2020.0.166.7z" -k -O 7z x
-aoa mkl_2020.0.166.7z -omkl   
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                               Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed 
100  103M  100  103M  0     0  5063k      0  0:00:21  0:00:21 --:--:-- 5629k
0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--     0curl: (6) Could not resolve host: 7z
0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--     0curl: (6) Could not resolve host: x 
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: mkl_2020.0.166.7z
```

There is actually a line break before "7z", with "7z" as the executable (and before, in addition to adding curl to your `user PATH`, you need to add 7z to the `user PATH` as well, for example with `setx PATH "%PATH%;C:\Program Files\7-Zip\"`):

> REM Download MKL files
>
> `curl https://s3.amazonaws.com/ossci-windows/mkl_2020.0.166.7z -k -O`
>
> `7z x -aoa mkl_2020.0.166.7z -omkl`

Answer (score 1):

In ubuntu like system this mainly occurs when we don’t have nameservers in the `/etc/resolv.conf`

So, we added the following line in the file.

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

Then, this fixed the error and the host started resolving.

Comment: in my rasperry pi I was able to solve the problem using your suggestion, however, the issue pops up frequently. This resolf.conf file frequently missing this line `nameserver 8.8.8.8` . Do you know how to solve the issue forever?

Answer (score 0):

Windows consoles usually doesnt interpret double quotes correctly in a JSON array, so you can solve it adding a slash / before double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I copied the curl that swagger generated and got the following errors:

- URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
- Could not resolve host: application
- unmatched close brace/bracket in URL position 1

Here's the original one:

```bash
curl -X 'POST' \ 'http://localhost:1000/Schedule/0' \ -H 'accept: */*' \ -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \ -d '{ "title": "string", "timeStart": "21:00:00", "timeEnd": "22:00:00" }'
```

To make this work I had to replace the single quotes with double quotes and
remove all backslash and add backslash to `--data` before each double quote

Final version:

```bash
curl -X POST "http://localhost:1000/Schedule/0" -H "accept: */*" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{ \\"title\\": \\"string\\", \\"timeStart\\": \\"21:00:00\\", \\"timeEnd\\": \\"22:00:00\\" }"
```

Answer (score 0):

It varies significantly with the version of Windows, in my case with 64-bit Windows Server 2022 Datacenter, space behind colon notation was OK, double quotes outside a string with double quotes inside was not OK, I had to use single quotes outside of the string, and use \" to replace " everywhere inside. Finally, the entire command had to be broken down into two lines before the last single quote, or it wouldn't work.