# Getting curl: (6) Could not resolve host: localhost

Tags: curl

Getting curl: (6) Could not resolve host: localhost

I'm facing an issue when calling a localhost url through `curl`. I did check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36361572/curl-6-could-not-resolve-host-application)  but it didn't help me.

My curl command:

```
curl --data "ip=127.0.0.1&device_type=web" http://localhost/api/users/getToken.json
```

Also tried the solution in this selected answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/40078901/1225070

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data "ip=127.0.0.1&device_type=web" http://localhost/api/users/getToken.json
```

However, the above command is working if I run it using the IP address

```
curl --data "ip=127.0.0.1&device_type=web" http://192.168.1.1/api/users/getToken.json
```

Any help why this is not working when using localhost?

Comment: why don't you use IP if it works for you?

Comment: @Moin, I can use IP but I want to know why the localhost is not working.

Answer (score 4):

I was getting the same error and figured out my `/etc/hosts` didn't have the localhost mapping it was supposed to have.

If you run `cat /etc/hosts` and if it doesn't show you a line with the following content, then you have the same problem I had:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

To fix this just add a line like the previous one to your `/etc/hosts` file. You can also to this by running:

```
sudo echo "127.0.0.1 localhost" >> /etc/hosts
```