# Curl request .curl: (6) Could not resolve host:

Tags: curl

I am using curl to download a file from an online web page but it gives this error:

> curl: (6) Could not resolve host: jsonplaceholder.typicode.com.

However, it works fine when I run on localhost xampp.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [curl: (6) Could not resolve host: application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36361572/curl-6-could-not-resolve-host-application)

Answer (score 0):

Actually it works:

```
curl -I jsonplaceholder.typicode.com
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

Moreover:

```
curl https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1 -s -o /tmp/x.json && cat /tmp/x.json
{
  "userId": 1,
  "id": 1,
  "title": "delectus aut autem",
  "completed": false
}
```